# Update HTML without using field in Component class - less stateful way

Tags: angular6, angular7

Say we have a Component class like so:

```
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-comp',
   })
    export class Component {

      v: any;

      template: `
        <div>{{v.bar}}</div>
      `

      constructor(){}

      onChange(v: any){
        this.v = v;
      }
    }
```

my question is - instead of using v as a class property - is there any way to update the HTML without having to assign v to the instance?

Instead of calling `this.v = v`, perhaps there is some Angular call we can use, `this.updateView({v});` - this would be less stateful way of doing it I suppose.

Comment: In two way binding, you have to assign the variable [which is coming from API response etc.] to the local variable to access that particular value in HTML

Comment: Why not use angular's data binding?

Comment: @LLai I don't want the component to store any state

Comment: Angular's data binding is alot cleaner than the alternatives, vanilla js `element.innerHtml` or angulars template ref